# Swiper slide - using animate.css to animate elements within slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, animate.css

**EDIT:** I figured out what the problem is, when the slide is set to `loop: true`, it will show the effect that the element is sliding twice. How can I resolve this without turning loop to false?

--

I'm using the swiper slider alongside animate.css to animate some elements inside a slide. I am trying to get a specific element to slide in from the right (slideInRight).

For this, I initially set the `visibility` of the element to `hidden` and then add the animated class to the element and set the visibility to visible inside the `setTimeout` method.

It works, however there'a a slight bug, the slide in effect looks like its going through 2 cycles. It should just seamlessly slide in from the right and fall into it's place. To see in action, run the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    }
  });

  var swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.slide-container').css({
      'visibility': 'visible',
      'opacity': '1'
    }).addClass('animated slideInRight animate-duration-100');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sy-title').css({
      'visibility': 'visible'
    }).addClass('animated slideInRight');
  }, 1600);

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #3E3E3E;
}

.swiper-container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.slide-container {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
}

span.sy-title {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="img-container-1">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide1">
        </div>
        <div class="sy-info">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container-2">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide1">
        </div>
        <div class="sy-availability">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
          <div class="img-container-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="img-container-1">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide2">
        </div>
        <div class="sy-info">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container-2">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide2">
        </div>
        <div class="sy-availability">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
          <div class="img-container-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/500x300?text=slide2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please correct the HTML structure, because of what the slider is showing multiple cycles.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    }
  });

  var swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.slide-container').css({
      'visibility': 'visible',
      'opacity': '1'
    }).addClass('animated slideInRight animate-duration-100');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sy-title').css({
      'visibility': 'visible'
    }).addClass('animated slideInRight');
  }, 1600);

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #3E3E3E;
}

.swiper-container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.slide-container {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
}

span.sy-title {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="img-container-1">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://image.yachtcharterfleet.com/charter-CLOUD-9/CLOUD-9-1.jpg?image_id=519748&k=3f0e&w=973&h=470&q=95&o=wc">
            <div class="sy-info">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      
 <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="img-container-2">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://image.yachtcharterfleet.com/charter-CLOUD-9/CLOUD-9-1.jpg?image_id=519748&k=3f0e&w=973&h=470&q=95&o=wc">
            <div class="sy-availability">
          <span class="sy-title">WATCH THIS TEXT ANIMATION</span>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>


 <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="img-container-3">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://image.yachtcharterfleet.com/charter-CLOUD-9/CLOUD-9-1.jpg?image_id=519748&k=3f0e&w=973&h=470&q=95&o=wc">
        </div>
      </div>

</div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You haven't corrected my HTML structure, you have altered it. One slide is meant to have multiple elements.

Comment: @Manpreet first thing is you have not indented the code provided in the question. the second thing you have initiated the animation only on page load, not on the slide change. Please edit your answer improve and post it.